# Error: Too Many initializer Values in Jaggled Arrays

Tags: c++

I have been Searching for solution for a long time, and didn't find how to solve it.

The Problem is :
Every time i declare an array it gives an error on 2nd value
Code:

```
// OpenGL Code

vertices[NumVertices][2] =
{
    { -0.90F, -0.90F }, // Triangle 1
    {  0.85F, -0.90F }, // Error: too many initlializer values
    { -0.90F,  0.85F },
    {  0.90F, -0.85F }, // Triangle 2
    {  0.90F,  0.90F  ,
    { -0.90F,  0.90F }
}; // Error: Expected a '}'
```

Any help?
Thankes for your time

Comment: You're clearly missing a `}`, as the error points out.

Comment: Were i am missing?

Comment: [Compiles fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8952c6fa627014d1) if you add the missing `}` (which you already knew about)

Comment: It worked for the second error not the first

Comment: Can you provide code that actually reproduces this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that `NumVertices` is not that you think.

Try this instead:

```
const unsigned NumVertx = 6; 
double vertices[NumVertx][2] =
{
    { -0.90F, -0.90F }, // Triangle 1
    {  0.85F, -0.90F }, 
    { -0.90F,  0.85F },
    {  0.90F, -0.85F }, // Triangle 2
    {  0.90F,  0.90F },
    { -0.90F,  0.90F }
};
```

Comment: It Worked, by changing the float to double, But can you link a page explaining why this deffer?

Comment: @AyhamAbouAlFadl it works for `float vertices[NumVertx][2]` too. Are you sure that the only change was this? I think that your ploblem was the type or value of `NumVertices` That is why I add `const unsigned NumVertx = 6;`